# Unable to save / Unable to create temp file

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am just getting set with PHP and am trying to run a simple 'Hello World', however it wont let me save.  I am getting this error:"Unable to save /private/etc/apache2/extra/

What gives? Hey is my file's measly two lines of code, let me know if you need anything else. Frustrating!!!

```
<?php

echo 'Hello World';
```

Edit... I am wondering if my error is in here

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/micahsherman/Documents/workspace/dev"
    ServerName micahsherman.local
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/micahsherman.local-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/micahsherman.local-access_log" common

    <Directory "Users/micahsherman/Documents/workspace/dev">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Possibly your text editor isn't running as root. You need to use root privileges to write to `/private/etc`.

Comment: not a good place to be putting your files. create a web root

Comment: Yes. PHP files don't belong under the `/etc` folder.

Comment: So how do I go about changing that? Andrew Medico and Dagon.

Comment: Please add the PHP closing tag ?>

Comment: @kimbarcelona It's best to exclude the closing `?>` tag, unless you want to output some HTML after it.

Comment: Can you help with the real problem of saving to the correct directory?

Comment: @m.sherman Make sure mod_userdir module is enabled in Apache, and then create a public web folder for yourself in your home directory.  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html

Comment: I am not using WAMP, what is that?

Comment: I added some code of my virtual host and directory...  Anything in there I should change?

By the way, I appreciate all of the help.

Comment: So then put your PHP script into `/Users/micahsherman/Documents/workspace/dev` and point your browser to `http://localhost/the_name_of_your_script_file.php` and it should show up.

Answer (score 0):

If they somehow got made read-only, you probably need to reset that through a batch script or the Properties dialog. In Windows, Just Right click on the file -> Properties-> Untick Read-Only -> Apply and Ok.